# Download multiple URLs at once

Tags: wget, download

I'm aware of `wget -i` as a way to download a list of URLs. The only trouble is that I need to pass some different POST data to each one, which works for single urls using `wget --post-data=` but not for lists.

I'm open to any CLI downloader, or even something in JS or Python. I would however like to get either a progress bar for each download or a log file updated each time a dl finishes, or some other way of knowing when a dl finishes.

Comment: Each URL has a different POST or they all have the same?

Comment: Many methods shown here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8634109/parallel-download-using-curl-command-line-utility

Answer (score 4):

If you already have a list of URLs, just add the POST data to that list. Something like:

```
www.example.com    postdata1
www.foo.com
www.bar.com       second_post_data
```

Then, instead of using `-i`, read the file in a bash loop and pass the data to wget:

```
while read url post; do wget --post-data="$post" $url; done < list.txt
```

To run them in parallel so that multiple files are downloaded at the same time, use `&` instead of `;`. Careful though, this will launch a separate `wget` process for each URL.

```
while read url post; do wget --post-data="$post" $url & done < list.txt
```

One trick I use for launching this type of thing is keeping track of how many are currently running and only running the next one if the number is below a threshold, 10 for example:

```
while read url post; do 
 while [[ "$(pgrep -fc wget)" -gt 9 && $c -gt 10 ]]; do sleep 1; done; 
 ((c++));  
 echo "Launching $url ($c)"; 
 wget --post-data="$post" $url >/dev/null 2>&1 && echo "$c finsihed" & 
done < list.txt
```

That will launch the first 10 URLs, then wait for one to finish and launch the next.

Answer (score 2):

You can define a delimited file CSV like with this format (for example) :

```
URL1;POSTDATA1
URL2;POSTDATA2
...
```

and parse it using an `awk` command :

```
awk -F\; '{print "wget -i "$1" --post-data="$2}' your_CSV_file
```

Answer (score 2):

I've not used this tool before but thought I'd add it since it sounds exactly like what you're looking for.

#### uget

It's a GUI tool called [`uget`](http://ugetdm.com/). It has the ability to take a input file that would contain the URLs to download along with HTTP POST data from a second file. It's unclear if this allows you to use different POST data per URL or if it's only a single set for all the URLs but might be worth a closer look.

```
$ uget-gtk --help
...
  -i, --input-file=FILE         add URLs found in FILE.
  --http-post-data=STRING       use the POST method; send STRING as the data.
  --http-post-file=FILE         use the POST method; send contents of FILE
```

**screenshots**

[image: ss #1]

[image: ss #2]